# Some print functions do not run in this calculation class. Why?

Tags: java

Alongside with my main class, i want to output the table with the points of the airfoil to the command line, but right now some of the system print functions aren't working. here is my calc class:

```
package airfoil;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class airfoil
{   
    private static final int numOfCoord = 250;
    double dx = 1.0 / numOfCoord;

    private double      m;      // maximum camber in % of chord
    private double      p;      // chordwise position of max ord., 10th of chord
    private double      t;      // thickness in % of the cord

    private String      nacaNum;        // NACA number - 4 digits
    private double[][]  coordinates;    // Coordinates of the upper half
                                        // or lower half of the airfoil
    private double[][]  meanLine;       // mean line coordinates

    public airfoil(String number) {

        nacaNum = number;
        m = Double.parseDouble(nacaNum.substring(0,1)) / 100.0;
        p = Double.parseDouble(nacaNum.substring(1,2)) / 10.0;
        t = Double.parseDouble(nacaNum.substring(2,4)) / 100.0;

        meanLine = new double[2][numOfCoord];  // x values row 0, y values row 1

        // x upper = row 0, 
        // y upper = row 1,
        // x lower = row 2,
        // y lower = row 3
        coordinates = new double [4][numOfCoord];

        System.out.println("NACA: " + nacaNum);
        System.out.println("Number of coordinates: " + numOfCoord);

        calcMeanLine();
        calcAirfoil();
    }

    /*
     * Calculates the values for the mean line forward of the maximum
     * ordinate and aft of the maximum ordinate.  
     */
    private void calcMeanLine() {

        double x = dx;
        int j = 0;

        // fwd of max ordinate
        while (x <= p) {
            meanLine[0][j] = x;
            meanLine[1][j] = (m / (p * p))*(2*p*x - (x*x));
            x += dx;
            j++;
        }

        // aft of max ordinate
        while (x <= 1.0 + dx) {
            meanLine[0][j] = x;
            meanLine[1][j] = (m / ((1 - p) * (1 - p))) *
                             ((1 - 2*p) + 2*p*x - x * x);
            x += dx;
            j++;
        }
    }  // end calcMeanLine

    /*
     * Calculate the upper and lower coordinates of the airfoil surface.
     */
    private void calcAirfoil() {

        double theta;       // arctan(dy_dx)
        double dy;          // derivative of mean line equation
        double yt, ml;      // thickness and meanline values, respectively
        double x = dx;      // x-value w.r.t. chord
        int j = 0;          // counter for array

        // calculate upper/lower surface coordinates fwd of max ordinate
        while (x <= p) {

            dy = (m / (p*p)) * (2*p - 2*x);
            theta = Math.atan(dy);
            yt = thicknessEQ(x);
            ml = meanLine[1][j];

            // upper surface coordinates;
            coordinates[0][j] = x - yt * Math.sin(theta);
            coordinates[1][j] = ml + yt * Math.cos(theta);

            // lower surface coordinates
            coordinates[2][j] = x + yt*Math.sin(theta);
            coordinates[3][j] = ml - yt * Math.cos(theta);

            x += dx;
            j++;
        }

        // calculate the coordinates aft of max ordinate
        while (x <= 1.0 + dx) {

            dy = (m / ((1 - p) * (1 - p))) * ((2 * p) - (2 * x));
            theta = Math.atan(dy);

            yt = thicknessEQ(x);
            ml = meanLine[1][j];

            // upper surface coordinates;
            coordinates[0][j] = x - yt * Math.sin(theta);
            coordinates[1][j] = ml + yt * Math.cos(theta);

            // lower surface coordinates
            coordinates[2][j] = x + yt * Math.sin(theta);
            coordinates[3][j] = ml - yt * Math.cos(theta);

            x += dx;
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println("j = " + j);
    } // end calcAirfoil

    /*
     * Thickness equation
     */
    private double thicknessEQ(double x) {

        return ((t / 0.2) * (0.2969 * Math.sqrt(x) - (0.126 * x) - 
                (0.3526 * x * x) + (0.28430 * x * x * x) - 
                (0.1015 * x * x * x * x)));
    }

    public String toString() {

        String str = "";
        NumberFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");

        System.out.println("Xu\tYu\tXl\tYl");

            for (int j = 0; j < numOfCoord; j++) {
                str += df.format(coordinates[0][j]) + "\t" + 
                       df.format(coordinates[1][j]) + "\t" +
                       df.format(coordinates[2][j]) + "\t" + 
                       df.format(coordinates[3][j]) + "\n";
            }

        return str;
    }

    /*
     * Return the coordinates array
     */
    public double[][] getCoordinates() { return coordinates; }
    public int getSize() { return numOfCoord; }

} // end Airfoil class
```

This part of the class is supposed to print a table, but it isnt doing anything:

```
public String toString() {

    String str = "";
    NumberFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");

    System.out.println("Xu\tYu\tXl\tYl");

    for (int j = 0; j < numOfCoord; j++) {
        str += df.format(coordinates[0][j]) + "\t" + 
               df.format(coordinates[1][j]) + "\t" +
               df.format(coordinates[2][j]) + "\t" + 
               df.format(coordinates[3][j]) + "\n";
    }
    return str;
}
```

So what can I do to make these things print correctly?

Comment: You are printing just one line with this string `"Xu\tYu\tXl\tYl"` you may be wanting to add this `System.out.println` inside your `for` after the variable assignment. And with the STR variable inside it.

Comment: Where are you calling toString()? If you're not calling it, it has no way to print.

Comment: dx = 1.0 / numOfCoord; he just formated badly

Comment: toString method should not print anything but just construct the object string representation. The print operation should be done outside.

Comment: So, make coordinates.toString(); in the main class to print?

Comment: You need to call `airfoil.toString()` somewhere and `System.out.println` the result that it returns -- it returns a string, it doesn't print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `System.out.println("Xu\tYu\tXl\tYl");` code prints the following: `Xu Yu  Xl  Yl` because you did not add any variables to it. You could change it to:

```
public String toString() {
    String str = "";
    NumberFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");

        for (int j = 0; j < numOfCoord; j++) {
            str += df.format(coordinates[0][j]) + "\t" + 
                   df.format(coordinates[1][j]) + "\t" +
                   df.format(coordinates[2][j]) + "\t" + 
                   df.format(coordinates[3][j]) + "\n";
        }

    System.out.println(str);
    return str;
}
```

Anyway, don't print in `toString()` function. `toString()` shouldn't print anything, it should just return the String so that you can print it or do whatever you want with it.

```
Airfoil airfoil = new Airfoil(); // Yes, first letter uppercase recommended
// do stuff
System.out.println(airfoil.toString());
```

EDIT: It works for me (I think). I used the input `1000` (by the way, you should use try/catch for numbers with 3 characters or less or it will crash), and this is the output I got (only the beginning and ending), as it's long.

```
NACA: 1000
Number of coordinates: 250
j = 250
0.0040  0.0100  0.0040  0.0100
0.0080  0.0100  0.0080  0.0100
0.0120  0.0100  0.0120  0.0100
[...]
0.9920  0.0002  0.9920  0.0002
0.9960  0.0001  0.9960  0.0001
1.0000  -0.0000 1.0000  -0.0000
```

This is the `toString()` code used to make it work:

```
public String toString() {
    String str = "";
    NumberFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");

    // System.out.println("Xu\tYu\tXl\tYl");

    for (int j = 0; j < numOfCoord; j++) {
        str +=  df.format(coordinates[0][j]) + "\t" +
                df.format(coordinates[1][j]) + "\t" + 
                df.format(coordinates[2][j]) + "\t" + 
                df.format(coordinates[3][j]) + "\n";
    }
    return str;
}
```

And the main I used:

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    Airfoil air = new Airfoil("1000");
    System.out.println(air.toString());
}
```

Comment: Adding system.out.println(str); doesnt do anything after compiling and re-running the code. the Xu Yu X1 Y1 is supposed to be formatting, Xu for x coordinates under the airfoil, Yu for coordinates under the airfoil, etc etc

Comment: You're the best. Thank you very much! not sure why `Airfoil airfoil = new Airfoil();` didnt work in the beginning. Maybe it's because the name "airfoil" was having problems with some of the other names. I changed the constant "1000" to nacaNum, which was what my scanner input effected, so the file is fully functional now. I'll probably work on implementing a GUI in the near future, and the ability to export as .txt. Shouldnt be that hard. Thank you!